# Minimizing/Maximizing triangle

Tags: calculus

[image: The problem:]

I plugged in the Y point e^(-x/3) into the equation (1/2)XY, found the derivate and set it equal to zero.

But I am only getting one value of X=3 (max). How do I get the min?

Comment: Yeah which is a dead thread. I need some new ideas.

Comment: Then you should edit the original one with further questions.  That will bump it back onto the list.

Comment: I tried that but I wasn't getting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no local minimum. For absolute min, you just plug in the end point of the domain, 1 and 5. The one with smaller A-value is your min (absolute minimum).